# How to a mock a function call within a function?

Tags: scala, playframework, mockito, scalatest

I'm creating unit tests for a PlayFramework Scala app and came across a function I need to test, which makes a command line interface call. This cli call can't be run in our test environment so I'd like to mock it.

```
class Foo @Inject()(val bar: Bar, val a: A, val b: B...) {
    def testThis(...) = {
        ...
        callCommandLine
        ...
    }
}

class Bar() {
    def callCommandLine(s: String): String = {
        ...
    }
}
```

Below is what I tried

```
class FooSpec() {
    "testFoo" in {
        val foo = app.injector.instanceOf[Foo]
        val result = testThis(...)

        val bar = mock[Bar]
        val mockedOutput = "fake cmd line result"
        when(bar.callCommandLine(anyString)).thenReturn(mockedOutput)

        result mustBe mockedOutput
    }
}
```

I understand why my test doesn't work, but I don't know what I need to do to make it work. Am I supposed to inject the mocked bar class into foo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your code is actually

```
class Foo @Inject()(val bar: Bar, val a: A, val b: B...) {
    def testThis(...) = {
        ...
        bar.callCommandLine()  // <-- difference here
        ...
    }
}
```

The obstacle you're facing is arising because you're using the "actual" application and its dependency injection container to construct `Foo`. In the "actual" app, `Bar` is obviously bound to an actual `Bar` instance, not the mocked one you crate in the test.

To fix this, you have two options:

1. Create an instance of Foo manually:

```
"testFoo" in {
    val mockedBar = mock[Bar]
    when(mockedBar.callCommandLine(anyString)).thenReturn(...)
    val foo = new Foo(mockedBar, mock[A], mock[B], ...)
    foo.testThis shouldBe "expectedResult"
}
```

This way is simple and straightforward, but it completely mocks out other dependencies (`A`, `B`, etc.). In most cases, this is an acceptable (and even desirable) outcome, as it allows testing the code in `Foo` independently of dependencies behavior.

The disadvantage is obvious - this is not an integration test, so it covers less ground (i.e. `A` and `B` behavior), and does not test the actual components to be used in production, as it does not involve dependency injection in any way.

Personally, I'd recommend going this way - it will create a more "independent" or "orthogonal" test and will allow testing `Foo` under different behaviors of all the dependencies it has.

2. Create a test-specific dependency injection container and have `Bar` mocked there.

```
val mockedBar = mock[Bar]
val app = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
  .overrides(bind[Bar].toInstance(mockedBar))
  .build()

"testFoo" in {
    when(mockedBar.callCommandLine(anyString)).thenReturn(...)
    val foo = app.injector.instanceOf[Foo]
    foo.testThis shouldBe "expectedResult"
}
```

note this snippet doesn't reset the mock after use, but this should be trivial to do using `beforeEach`. A better way would be to create a new instance of `mockedBar` for each test, but I'll omit it here for brevity.

There is a section in [PlayFramework documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaTestingWithGuice#Overriding-bindings-in-a-functional-test) covering this particular use case.

This approach is more like integration test - all dependencies but `Bar` use actual implementations, with all advantages and disadvantages it brings.

Comment: This is the right answer, but I'd like to add that for resetting the mocks after each test, you can use this https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala#orgmockitointegrationsscalatestresetmocksaftereachtest

Comment: @Bruno +1, but resetting mocks is discouraged by [mockito itself](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#17)

Comment: I know, but sometimes you need to wire them to play (like to test your JSON api) and that's the less boilerplatish way to deal with it. I totally agree that your first solution is better if the component can be tested in isolation from the framework